# Joins and count accross several tables

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sum, self-join

I'm trying to write a complex (at least, for my level of knowledge) string but I'm having one hell of a time.

Here's the problem.  I have two tables, one named t1 and one named c1.

The tables are defined as follow:

```
table T1:

e_id, char(8),  
e_date, datetime,  
e_status, varchar(2)

table C1:

e_id, char(8),  
e_date, datetime,  
e_status, varchar(2)
```

Each table contains a list of identifiers that may or may not be found in both tables (they may or may not be unique within each table), and associated statuses (can be 'OK' or 'R' in the T1 table, can be 'OK' or 'C' in the C1 table), and a datetime, e_date, associated with each occurence of e_id's

I'm trying to write a query that will:

- Retrieve all the e_id values in the T1 table that have an `e_date` that is within the last 24 hours.
- Retrieve all the occurences of the e_id's that have occured within the last 24hrs (**e_date is bigger than current time - 24h**) in T1 within the last 30 days (e_date > now - 30 days), still within table T1 (**eg: if e_id's AAAAAAAA and BBBBBBBB are found in t1 with an e_date that is within the last 24 hours, retrieve all the occurences of e_id's AAAAAAAA and BBBBBBBB in the same table but that have an e_date that is within the last 30 days**)
- Append the count of `e_status = 'OK'` for each specific `e_id` found in the entire `T1 table` to the row results
- Append the count of `e_Status = 'OK'` for each specific `e_id` found in the entire `C1 table` to the row results

I'll do my best to write some sample data/results here.  For clarity, I will disregard the tables datatypes.  Assume the current date and time are 2012-Nov-08 19:00:00

T1:

1. e_id: **'A'**, e_date: **2012-Nov-08 10:00:00**, e_status: **'OK'**
2. e_id: **'A'**, e_date: **2012-Nov-08 10:00:00**, e_status: **'R'**
3. e_id: **'A'**, e_date: **2012-Oct-15 10:00:00**, e_status: **'R'**
4. e_id: 'B', e_date: **2012-Oct-15 10:00:00**, e_status: **'OK'**
5. e_id: **'A'**, e_date: **2012-Oct-15 10:00:00**, e_status: **'OK'**
6. e_id: **'A'**, e_date: **2012-Oct-15 10:00:00**, e_status: **'R'**
7. e_id: **'A'**, e_date: **2012-Oct-15 10:00:00**, e_status: **'R'**
8. e_id: **'A'**, e_date: **2010-Jan-01 10:00:00**, e_status: **'R'**
9. e_id: **'A'**, e_date: **2010-Jan-01 10:00:00**, e_status: **'R'**

C1:

1. e_id: **'A'**, e_date: **2012-Oct-01 10:00:00**, e_status: **'C**
2. e_id: 'B', e_date: **2012-Oct-01 10:00:00**, e_status: **'OK'**
3. e_id: **'A'**, e_date: **2012-Oct-01 10:00:00**, e_status: **'C**
4. e_id: 'B', e_date: **2012-Oct-01 10:00:00**, e_status: **'OK'**
5. e_id: **'A'**, e_date: **2012-Oct-01 10:00:00**, e_status: **'OK'**

Running the query would yield:

e_id, e_date, e_status, r_count, c_count
1. e_id: **'A'**, e_date: **2012-Nov-08 10:00:00**, e_status: **'OK'**, r_count: **6**, c_count: **2**
2. e_id: **'A'**, e_date: **2012-Nov-08 10:00:00**, e_status: **'R'**, r_count: **6**, c_count: **2**
3. e_id: **'A'**, e_date: **2012-Oct-15 10:00:00**, e_status: **'R'**, r_count: **6**, c_count: **2**
4. e_id: **'A'**, e_date: **2012-Oct-15 10:00:00**, e_status: **'OK'**, r_count: **6**, c_count: **2**
5. e_id: **'A'**, e_date: **2012-Oct-15 10:00:00**, e_status: **'R'**, r_count: **6**, c_count: **2**
6. e_id: **'A'**, e_date: **2012-Oct-15 10:00:00**, e_status: **'R'**, r_count: **6**, c_count: **2**

I am really sorry, I have had to change the date on T1 rows 3 to 7 (rows 3 4 5 6 of the results) as the values were erroneous.

T1's Row 4 was not returned because no `e_id: B` was found in the last 24 hours
T1 Rows 8 and 9 were not returned because they were outside of the last 30 days

Comment: Can you provide the definition of the tables?  Also, I have no idea what you mean by the second bullet point.  Do you want the counts within the last 30 days and through the whole table?  If not, the bullet does not make sense.

Comment: There you go, I've modified the post.  I hope this clarifies and I thank you for the reply!

Comment: The (relevant) table columns with some sample data and desired output would be a big help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time to do some TDQD — Test-Driven Query Design.

#### Rows in T1 from the last 24 hours

```
SELECT DISTINCT e_id
  FROM T1
 WHERE e_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

This will be a prevalent sub-query in the other parts of the query.

#### Rows in T1 from the last 30 days...

...where there was an entry in T1 within the last 24 hours.

```
SELECT a.e_id
  FROM t1 AS a
  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT e_id
          FROM T1
         WHERE e_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
       ) AS b ON b.e_id = a.e_id
 WHERE a.e_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

We can add other columns as we need them.

#### Count of rows in T1 with status 'R' ...

...where there was an entry in T1 within the last 24 hours

```
SELECT a.e_id, COUNT(*) AS r_count  -- Per question; why not t_count?
  FROM t1 AS a
  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT e_id
          FROM T1
         WHERE e_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
       ) AS b ON b.e_id = a.e_id
 WHERE a.e_status = 'R'
 GROUP BY a.e_id
```

#### Count of rows in C1 with status 'C' ...

...where there was an entry in T1 within the last 24 hours

```
SELECT a.e_id, COUNT(*) AS c_count
  FROM c1 AS a
  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT e_id
          FROM T1
         WHERE e_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
       ) AS b ON b.e_id = a.e_id
 WHERE a.e_status = 'C'
 GROUP BY a.e_id
```

#### Assemble the set of queries to produce the result

```
SELECT a.e_id, a.e_date, a.e_status, c.r_count, d.c_count
  FROM t1 AS a
  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT e_id
          FROM T1
         WHERE e_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
       ) AS b ON b.e_id = a.e_id
  LEFT JOIN -- Because there might be no OK rows in T1
       (SELECT a.e_id, COUNT(*) AS r_count
          FROM t1 AS a
          JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT e_id
                  FROM T1
                 WHERE e_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
               ) AS b ON b.e_id = a.e_id
         WHERE a.e_status = 'OK'
         GROUP BY a.e_id
       ) AS c ON c.e_id = a.e_id
  LEFT JOIN -- Because there might be no OK rows in C1
       (SELECT a.e_id, COUNT(*) AS c_count
          FROM c1 AS a
          JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT e_id
                  FROM T1
                 WHERE e_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
               ) AS b ON b.e_id = a.e_id
         WHERE a.e_status = 'OK'
         GROUP BY a.e_id
       ) AS d ON d.e_id = a.e_id
 WHERE a.e_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

You probably could write the sub-queries without the 24 hour sub-sub-query, but it is likely to be effective to eliminate as many rows as soon as possible.

---

One advantage of the concept behind TDQD is that you can check interim results.  There were some basically trivial syntax issues (in part because MySQL is not my primary DBMS), but the change from JOIN to LEFT JOIN for the two COUNT sub-queries is the sort of thing you're apt to spot as you assemble the query.  Trying to get everything right first time is — hard, if not futile.  But the step-by-step build-up can give you confidence in what you've done.  I'd never build a query as complex as this from scratch without testing the component sub-queries.

Thanks for the (minor) updates, [FatalMojo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/309689/fatalmojo).

Comment: My mind, you have just blown sir!  I'll try this as soon as possible (I do not have access to the server from where I am right now).  Thank you for the amazing answer and the amount of detail.  I will let you know how it turns out!

Comment: If the final result is not correct, then check the individual queries, tweaking each one until it is correct, and then assemble the result.  You might even decide to check the first query — the one which becomes the sub-query everywhere else — before trying the final result.  Note that I don't use MySQL; I'm not certain of the DATE_SUB() syntax, but I did check the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html).  Dates and times are the most variable component of SQL DBMS, in terms of how the functionality is implemented compared to other SQL DBMS.

Comment: Haha, so far so good, I'm working the queries one at a time and digesting it!  I actually set up a local server with a sample table because I couldn't wait!  The DATE_SUBs are great, however, the intervals are not plurals in MySQL, so it's DAY instead of DAYS, HOUR instead of HOURS, and so on and so forth.  I think this is going to work, I am so ever grateful! :D

Comment: No need to apologize!  I've realized so many things through your post already!  One last thing though, this seems to omit rows if the r_count or c_count are 0, is there any way to show the rows regardless?

Comment: Okay, LEFT JOIN on the two count queries did the trick :)  Jonathan, thank you for the answer.  I hope one day I'll be able to pass the knowledge along!